# Div does not fit browser's width when using media queries

Tags: css

I am trying to make the left box and the right box stack vertically when seen on a screen 600px or less. I can make the nav bar do that. However I am unable to make the boxes do what the nav bar is doing. Floating, `width`s and `max-width`s do not seem to help, maybe I am using it wrongly? My desired goal is make right box appear underneath left box with no overlap and no overflow.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #fff5db;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.links-box {
  background-color: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right-content {
  background-color: #fff5db;
  position: relative;
  left: 21%;
  max-width: 79%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #logo {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .topnav {
    float: none;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: none;
  }
  .sidebar {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: content-box;
  }
  .introduction {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  .right-content {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="">link1</a>
  <a href="">link2</a>
  <a href="">link3</a>
  <a href="">link4</a>
  <a href="">link5</a>
  <a href="">link6</a>
</div>


<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="links-box">left box</div>
</div>

<div class="right-content">right box</div>
```

([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/74c1b60z/))

Comment: because you have absolutely positioned them

Comment: floats are going to make your life a lot difficult than it has to be. Consider using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It will make aligning elements left or right to each other really easy and flexible.

Comment: @Yousaf floats don't even matter when its `position: absolute;`

Comment: @zgood I know, I was just advising the OP to make use of `flexbox` instead of floats or any other css property to align elements left or right of each other.

Comment: You should probably rethink you layout and not use `position: absolute;` for your main layout elements since you want it to be responsive. Normally with a responsive layout you want content to "flow" and "wrap", and when you `position: absolute` you are preventing this type of behavior. A flexbox layout like @Yousaf recommended is a good approach.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, I'll redo my css. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Need to make `position: static` for both **.sidebar**  and **.right-content** within the media-query.

P.S: I Don't exactly know what you're trying to achieve but I think you are unnecessarily messing the position property.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was eventually redo-ing my code to use the 'flex' property and 'justify-content: center' to make the two boxes side by side instead of using absolute positioning to position them manually.

Using media queries after that was much easier.